# Creating a Dynamic Quiz using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to create a quiz with jquery and radio buttons. The link is an example of what I want to do. http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/jQuiz/. I want to create an object to store the questions and answers like so.

```
 var allQuestions = [
          {
          question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
          choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
          correctAnswer:0
          }
   ];.
```

I guess my question is where do I go from here? An outline would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you've already found an example of someone doing what you want to do, read their source code; that's always a good first step

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuizMe`: http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/qWjBq/

<kbd>[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/jquizme/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

1. Read The JSON Array Object.
2. iterate over it using jQuery.each(AllQuestions)
3. in the iteration read Question.
4. when you read question , read the choices array and do create another forEach over the array to read choices, print choices along with radio buttons.
5. Now you need to figure out the onclick of radio buttons. To print correct answer or wrong answer.